# XSS: is it still a problem?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, xss

Am I right to say that XSS isn't such a problem anymore? Since IE 8/Chrome block it anyway?

Comment: Do you have links for resources relating to IE8 and Chrome's XSS detection features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, browsers have improved allot against XSS attacks. But please, **NEVER** thrust user input. For example a XSS attack tactic that still works.

## **- Escaping HTML tags.**

> [example] 
>   You have a search engine website with a profile that other
>    people can see your saved searches. 
>   [/example]

When your users has the ability to save search results and share them with other users and the user save this result: `" /> <iframe src=[malware]></iframe>` the `" />` shuts down the tag and makes it possible to enter the hackers code after it. Making it possible to steal sessions, insert images or redirect the user to another website.

This is just a little example that still works, there are allot more. Try it yourself!

More info: http://heideri.ch/jso/#html

Answer (score 4):

No. You can still exploit XSS vulnerabilities if a page is vulnerable.

Comment: But not in IE8 and Chrome, so let's say all my users use that browser, than there is no problem, right?

Comment: @Kevin - Just because those browsers added some protection doesn't mean that every hole has been filled. Even Chrome and IE8 can be exploited by somebody who knows how.

Comment: Say it is possible, do you have an example of a possible XSS attack in one of those browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Malicious users have not disappeared.

A lot of XSS loopholes have closed in major browsers but there are still plenty of ways people can take advantage of you.

The only thing that's changed is that as a developer, defending against XSS is easier since there are less things to block / watch for.

Comment: But now I am talking about two browsers. Do you have an example of XSS attacks in that browsers?

Comment: @Kevin here's a [large list of vulnerabilities](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) try them all on your website in IE8 and chrome

Comment: Did not test all of them, but I am sure they all will be blocked;)

Comment: @Kevin I don't have that much trust in IE8 :) I'm sure there are loopholes

Comment: So it is just an assumption that IE8's filter does not block all XSS?

Comment: @Kevin rather safe then sorry.

Comment: @Kevin no, it's more of an assumption on your part that IE8 *does* block all XSS, because (I guess) you read that somewhere or something.